# passive os fingerprint change to MacOS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proxy, fingerprint

Ubuntu 16.04 server, proxy raised on the server (3proxy). When connected via a proxy with macbook, OS Fingerprint is defined as Linux 3.11 and never [fuzzy] (http://witch.valdikss.org.ru/)
At the moment, using non-complex manipulations with the /etc/sysctl.conf kernel settings, it turns out to change to Android (Linux 2.2.x-3.x [generic] [fuzzy]) and Windows NT.

Need to change the OS Fingerprint, so that http://witch.valdikss.org.ru/ defines the connection as Mac OS X [generic] [fuzzy]

Answer (score 1):

According to p0f `README` "one of the most valuable TCP fingerprinting signal" is TCP options layout. Applied to MacOS and Linux fingerprint entries this means we should change layout from:

```
mss,sok,ts,nop,ws
```

to

```
mss,nop,ws,nop,nop,ts,sok,eol+1
```

This cannot be done by sysctl since Linux kernel hardcode this order into `tcp_connect` syscall: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/bab5c80b211035739997ebd361a679fa85b39465/net/ipv4/tcp_output.c#L458

So you must write netfilter kernel module to mangle TCP options later like TCPMSS module does:
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/netfilter/xt_TCPMSS.c.

Either patching `tcp_connect` or writing custom netfilter module requires strong kernel programming skills.

Another option is to somehow intercept TCP `SYN/SYN+ACK` packets by user-space program (maybe nfqueue or tproxy with raw sockets can help), mangle it and write back to kernel. This can significantly hurt performance but easier to implement.

UPD: I've googled some working and dirty example of this technique based on nfqueue/python: https://forums.hak5.org/topic/33532-p0f-mangler/